# After upgrading from MaterialUI v4 to MaterialUI v5 - lack of default theme causing mount tests to fail. How to reinstate a default theme?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mocha.js, enzyme

In in my mocha test code I have have lots of tests that use mount.

```
enzyme.mount(<SomeComponentThatUsesMUI />);
```

This worked fine in material-ui v4. However in v5 due to the lack of a default theme, any code in `SomeComponentThatUsesMui` that attempts to access the theme

Now I know could wrap the component with a ThemeProvider :

```
 enzyme.mount(<ThemeProvider theme={} ><<SomeComponentThatUsesMUI /><ThemeProvider />);
```

However this means that subsequent test code will need adjusting, and this is 100+ tests. (5% of my tests).

Is there a way to reinstate, for the unittests, a default theme?

Answer (score 0):

***Warning: This answer modifies two internal fields (as they are in React 17.0.2).***

***This will break if the React Context object changes internally***

---

The cause of the `null` default theme is from:

`@mui/private-theming/node/useTheme/ThemeContext.js`

`const ThemeContext = /*#__PURE__*/React.createContext(null);`

When the createContext is called for ThemeContext, no default theme is set.

So one can add in unittest setup code (before your unittests run):

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

import('@mui/private-theming/node/useTheme/ThemeContext.js').then(ThemeContext => 
{
  let defaultTheme = React.createContext(createTheme({}));
  if (ThemeContext.default)
  {
    ThemeContext.default._currentValue = defaultTheme._currentValue;
    ThemeContext.default._currentValue2 = defaultTheme._currentValue2;
  }  
});
```

This modifies two internal fields, `_currentValue`, and `_currentValue2` to adjust the default ThemeContext to be equivalent to

`const ThemeContext = /*#__PURE__*/React.createContext(createTheme({}));`

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer requires modifying each mount statement,it doesn't require any subsequent changes to test code.

Provide `wrappingComponent` and `wrappingComponentProps` args to mount:

```
let wrapper = enzyme.mount(<SomeComponentThatUsesMUI />,
            {
                wrappingComponent: ThemeProvider,
                wrappingComponentProps: { theme: createTheme({}) }
            });
```

`SomeComponentThatUsesMUI` now has a theme, but wrapper still refers to `SomeComponentThatUsesMUI` and not ThemeProvider.

Comment: This solution is not working for me :(

Comment: I have a redux store provider too, so I am writing as const wrapper = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      
      <Multiple {...props} />
      
    </Provider>,
    {
      wrappingComponent: ThemeProvider,
      wrappingComponentProps: { theme: createTheme({}) }
  }
  ); But it is not helping